# qsort() from stdlib.h is not sorting a spezified structure containing zip-codes and corrresponding city

Tags: c, qsort

I'm using this gloabal crisis to study C beside my studies and i am following a german book (Rheinwerk Computing: C von A bis Z, ANSI-C99) and finally reached searching functions. As a practice I wanted to implement a sorting function to provide the functionallity of a binaray search.

My problem is, that whenever i add a new zip-structure they won't get sorteted. I was looking through different qestions here already and found out how to build a comparsion function for structures and how to handle structs with qsort. But it seems like that the answers didn't help or i am probably to dump to see it.

Technical enviorment:
I use vim and gcc (FLAGS: -Wpedantic -Wstrict-aliasing -Wshadow -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wfloat-equal) on a 32-Bit debian subsystem for windows. Since gcc is not complaining about anything while compiling the code, i wonder what i made wrong.

My code:

```
struct zipc
{
   char place[255];
   unsigned int zip;
};

struct zipc zipcodes[100];

static int N; //Counting how many adresses are already typed in

// create new zip with city, init function creates one with N=0 and dummy values

void insertbs(unsigned int p, char *o) 
{
    zipcodes[++N].zip = p;
    strcpy(zipcodes[N].place, o);
}

int cmp_uinteger(const void *value1, const void *value2)
{
   const struct zipc *p1 = value1;
   const struct zipc *p2 = value2;

   if(p1->zip > p2->zip) 
        return 1;
   if(p2->zip > p1->zip)
        return (-1);
   else 
        return 0;
}

//usage of qsort later in main

qsort(zipcodes, N-1, sizeof(unsigned int), cmp_uinteger);
```

The cmp_uinteger function is inspired by annother question here and seems to be pretty nice but the sort always fails, but not in a way that the program fails. The program is running but if one inserts zip codes in abitrary order, binary search fails, that's why i thinks it's about qsort() but i although can be somewhere else. I think i don't really get the point for the comparsion function maybe somebody can explain that too.

It feels strange to post my first question here because stack overflow become my second home during the C tutorial :D

Best greets,
Maleware

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned int)` should be `sizeof(struct zipc)`

Comment: "init function creates one with N=0 and dummy values". And if your first entry is a dummy one you should pass in `&zipcodes[1]` and not `zipcodes`. Otherwise it will include the dummy entry and miss the last real entry.

Comment: "gcc is not complaining about anything while compiling the code, i wonder what i made wrong". That is necessary but nowhere near sufficient for producing a fully functioning program. That's like saying "I was able to drive my car out the garage without crashing so I don't know why I didn't win the grand prix" :-)

Comment: @kaylum thank you very much for your answers. I didn't get your second advice, i guess. Why is &zipcodes[1] a pointer fitting into qsort()?

Your last one is very nice :D

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it is working fine, thank you so much :)

Maybe one more, why sizeof(struct zipc) when i just compare the zip?

Comment: Your comment in the code suggest that entry 0 of the array is a "dummy" one. I assume that means the real data starts from `zipcodes[1]`. You haven't shown the `init` code so I'm just going from your code comment. `qsort` takes a pointer to the base of the array you want to sort. Since your real data starts form `zipcodes[1]` then you should tell `qsort` to start there.

Comment: That size is needed because `qsort` needs to know the "stride" of each array entry. That is, it needs to know how to skip from one entry to the next so that it can pass a pointer to each entry to your comparator funcion.

Comment: Yeah you are right i am creating a dummy and so the entrie for N=0 only contains dummy informations. Mhhm i think i have it, helped a lot :)

So it's like giving qsort a roadmap, explaining how the value is ordered in the file it gets?

Answer (score 2):

```
qsort(zipcodes, N-1, sizeof(unsigned int), cmp_uinteger);
```

Third argument of `qsort()` *"Size in bytes of each element in the array"*.

In your case it should be `sizeof(struct zipc)` instead of `sizeof(unsigned int)`.

Answer (score 1):

With a dummy value at `zipcodes[0]`, sort from `zipcodes + 1` and use the size of an array element - easier to code right, review and maintain than attempting to code the size of a type (which was the wrong type in OP's code)

```
// qsort(zipcodes, N-1, sizeof(unsigned int), cmp_uinteger);
qsort(zipcodes + 1, N-1, sizeof zipcodes[0], cmp_uinteger);
```